# Inline iframe does not get loaded

Tags: html, iframe

If I create an HTML file with an inline iframe like this

```
<body>
    <iframe>
        <html>
            <body>
                Hello World!!
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>
</body>
```

and open the page in browser, nothing gets printed.
But if I specify a `<iframe src="test.php">` attribute, with `test.php` having the same code,

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello World!!
    </body>
</html>
```

as the inline iframe, I get "hello world" printed... why is that? Is an inline iframe not legal?

Comment: instead of <iframe> use <frame> tag for inline contents.

Comment: @Umar: frames require a src attribute as well, will not work outside a frameset (some browsers support that, but it's not standard) and, I believe, frames/framesets are (or will be) deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how iframes work. The src attribute specifies the content. If your browser doesn't support iframes then the inner HTML will be rendered. The usual pattern is:

```
<iframe src="contents.html">
Your browser doesn't support iframes!
</iframe>
```

The reason you don't see anything rendered is because your browser supports iframes.

Comment: so if we donot specify the "src" attribute, the browser will think the content is empty, and not look for it inside the iframe tags?

Comment: Yes, you can create an empty iframe and possibly add content later using JavaScript.